# Crystal Reports / IIS - Runtime Error

Tags: visual-studio, iis, crystal-reports

I have an asp.NET 4.0 Web Application which is Hosted on IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008 R2). The server has the following packages installed for Crystal Reports:

SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio 2010 - Standard
SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4 (64-bit)

I am using Visual Studio 2010 for Publishing, and should have all the necessary .dll files.

I have this error:

*An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.*

**Description:** *An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

**Exception Details:** *CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.*

What should I do to solve this error?

Comment: Has it ever worked? Does it work subsequently? Have you gone and `please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable` as it suggested?

Comment: @p.campbell - It never worked, the appropraite redistributables should have been installed with "SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio 2010" AND "Standard SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4 (64-bit)"

Answer (score 3):

Likely this error occurs because you've deployed to an x64 machine, and the Crystal binaries are 32-bit only.

There's some suggestion on this [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/82e23647-7116-424b-b437-df0cb2be083d/) that:

- Crystal doesn't initialize with a project build for x64.

Suggest converting your project's Platform Target (Any CPU, x86, x64) to **x86**. Likely this will be it.

Further down there are 2 more suggestions:

- J Fischer's steps on configuring IIS and your app pool to run 32 bit applications. Specifically the tweak is `enable32BitAppOnWin64` and 'Enable 32-Bit Applications to True'
- 32-bit ODBC

Comment: @p.cambell - this was eventually solved by making sure we were using the same versions both on the development machines and on the server.  Then we had some missing crystal reports file on the server which we had forgot to put in.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you install this runtime its gonna work it worked for us on our server

[Crystal reports 64bits runtime](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_3.zip)